# Analysis of Patristic Texts

Tags: discussion

So, say I have a question concerning the translation of a Patristic text, say, of Gregory of Nazianzus. It would go something like this:

---

In his first discourse, Gregory of Nazianzus wrote,

> εἴπωμεν, ἀδελφοὶ, καὶ τοῖς μισοῦσιν ἡμᾶς, μὴ ὅτι τοῖς δι' ἀγάπην τι πεποιηκόσιν, ἢ πεπονθό σι·

Such and such translated it as,

> Blah blah blah

I believe it would be more accurately translated as,

> Yada yada yada

Can someone offer some insight on the translation of the Greek text?

---

I don't think that question belongs on BH.SE. Does it have a place here at Christianity.SE?

Comment: My personal feeling would be "no".  This site is more about doctrine, and less about accurate translation from Hebrew, Greek, or Aramaic to English.  But I don't feel strongly enough about that to post that as an answer.

Comment: I was feeling the same way. Just wanted to be sure. Thanks!

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 Why is that off-topic at BH?

Comment: @fredsbend: I thought BH only involved scripture (i.e., the Bible).

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81 I honestly, don't know. I thought you knew.